# What should be the buffer size for transfering files over socket in java

Tags: java, sockets

It may be stupid questions but I want to know what should be the buffer size for
file transfer

Here is the code for sending the file

```
try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        jTextArea1.append("Accepted connection : " + socket+"\n");
        byte [] bytearray = new byte [10485760];      //Buffer size 10Mb
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(GetFile);
        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
        int read;
         OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        while((read=bin.read(bytearray))!=-1){
            jTextArea1.append("Sending Files...\n");//I have printed the read variable
            System.out.println("Read: "+read);
            os.write(bytearray,0,read);
            os.flush();

        }
        socket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
        System.out.println("File transfer complete\n");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BufferedFileTransfar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Note:- Input File size is 143mb so as per may buffer size file should be divided in 15 parts and it gets divided

Output:-

```
Read: 10485760
Read: 10485760
Read: 10485760
Read: 10485760
Read: 10485760
Read: 10485760
Read: 10485760
Read: 10485760
Read: 10485760
Read: 10485760
Read: 10485760
Read: 10485760
Read: 10485760
Read: 10485760
Read: 3603264
File transfer complete
```

So for the same file if I use large buffer then the it will be ok na?

Comment: Usual values are between `1024` and `8192`.

Comment: so should I decrease the buffer size

Comment: Well you're not gaining anything from having it that big.

Comment: @Kayaman8192 means 8 Byte

Comment: @kayamanok and can you tell me why?

Comment: @kayaman I have posted the code please go through it

Comment: Test your code with a 8KB array and a 1MB array and see the time it takes. How can you waste so much time on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it can be `1024` or `1024*16` or `1024*32`

And also you should test your application with different buffer sizes to determine which is the best. You can't guess ahead of time.

Comment: @BahramdunAdilI want to transfer large files fast so large buffer will do the trick right or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Common values for transfer buffers are in the few kilobytes (`1024` to `8192` or so) range. The reason for the small size is that there is no advantage in having a big buffer when the bottleneck is the actual transfer; bytes coming in small batches of few kilobytes tops. With a bigger buffer, only a small part of it will be used, the rest going to waste.

This can be easily tested with network or file transfer, starting with a tiny buffer of `8` bytes or so, and gradually increasing it. While the performance is clearly harmed by a small buffer, increasing it beyond few kilobytes no longer affects the performance.

Comment: What you want to say please explain

Comment: you are probably confusing him because 1 kilobyte is 1000 and 8 kilobytes are 8000 bytes not 8192 or 1024.

Comment: @JohnE. Unfortunately I don't think the kilo/kibibyte issue is the source to his confusion. You're a real smart-butt though, aren'tcha?